# Do I have to use JSONP for API subdomain?

Tags: json, angularjs, cross-domain

I'm setting up an app and it is to have the api hosted at `http://api.project.com` and the main app will be hosted at `https://app.project.com`.

The app will be a 100% angular.js based app. Is the only way for the app to communicate with the api going to be with JSONP? (Excluding CORS).

From my research the answer is probably yes but it's pretty unclear... so would be great to get this confirmed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: If you have cross domain API call then yes, jsonp will be the way for your app to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here your api is hosted at `http://api.project.com` and your app is hosted at `https://app.project.com`. So you will have cross domain API call. In that cases you have to use `jsonp`.

A good explanation for why you have to use JSONP can be found here;

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about
```

I hope this might help.

Comment: This is wrong. Several alternatives to JSON-P are listed in the duplicate question.

Comment: I definitely don't want to use an iFrame method, so the only other interesting alternative is the ProxyPass method... I think JSONP is still the most sensible option though.

Comment: I don't mean its a must to use jsonp if we have cross domain API call. I just mean jsonp is the sensible option here like markstewie said.